# jQuery sees every PHP response as having staus 0

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying to get javascript to check whether a user exists in a MySQL database.

To do this, I am using jQuery to Post the user details to a PHP script that checks the MySQL database.

The jQuery POST successfully passes the data to the PHP script. I have checked this:

- By having the PHP script email me to say it has got the data.
- By Tracing the call using Firebug
- By tracing the packet exchange using Wireshark

But, jQuery is determined to believe that every time it gets the response from the PHP script, that the status is 0.

In the firebug trace, and in the wireshark trace, the status in the HTML  response from the PHP script is ALWAYS "200 OK".

I have tried any number of ideas (suggested by lots of people who have hit a similar problem), like forcing the encoding to be json and setting the datatype in the jQuery POST call to be "json",  like putting a brief sleep in the PHP script,  like using a GET instead of a POST.

I have simplifed my HTML, javascript and PHP to just about the bare minimum, and still I cannot get jQuery to decide that the status of the response is anything but 0.

What I have got now :

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<SCRIPT SRC="Templates/nop_shopping_cart/jquery-1.7.2.js"></SCRIPT>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkUser()
{
 alert("clicked");
    jQuery.post( 'http://solfacats.com/dsadmin/valUser2.php', {email: "test", password:  "test"}, function(data) { alert("returned"+data)}, "html" );

}
</SCRIPT>

<body>
<button onclick="Javascript: checkUser();"> "test" </button>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php 
echo "test";
?>
```

Note - to trace what is going on, I have used calls to alert() in the done() function in jquery-1.7.2.js. One of the alerts pops up the value of the variable status that was passed to done(). This always shows the value of the variable status to be zero.

Also, note - if I hack the done() function by adding the line "status=200" early on in that function, then the callback function in the jQuery.post is called, but it believes that the value of the data variable passed to it is null.

I have tried this out on IE, Firefox and Safari, and get the same problem on them all.

Does anyone have some good pointers on where I should go from here to get jQuery to see the PHP response as successful, and to successfully extract the data from the response?

Comment: Does the JavaScript console display any error messages? The use of an absolute URI implies that you could be hitting the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: What headers is your PHP sending? You could use CURL to investigate

Comment: You should open chrome devtools (or firebug) and see what is the value you get in the response from the server.

Comment: +1 for huge research effort, though I feel like this post need to be edited to make things brief.

Answer (score 0):

Cant say how you are debugging your code, but for me clearly the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) preventing your AJAX request to different domain when I tried with your code.

You could use `JSON-P` with a `timeout` to verify whether AJAX was really called or not. If the request is timed out, then some networking issue is killing it. It can be tracked by the following code:

```
function checkUser() {
     alert("clicked");
     var email = "test";
     var password=  "test";
     var url = "http://solfacats.com/dsadmin/valUser2.php";
     $.ajax({
         url: url,
         type: "post",
         data: "email="+ email + "&password=" + password,
         dataType: 'jsonp', //it helps you in cross-domain data transfer
         crossDomain : true,
         timeout : 2500, /* it is in milliseconds (i have greater timeout 
                         as my net is very slow, generally a timeout of
                         500 milliseconds will be sufficient)*/
         complete : function(xhr, responseText, thrownError) {
             if(xhr.status == "200") {
                alert(responseText); //yes response came
             }
             else{
                alert("No response"); //no response came
             }
         }
     });
 }
```

By this you would be able to get response. But It will throw JS error in console. To pass data with JSON-P, you have to produce correctly formatted data in server-side. One valid example of response is :

```
parseResponse({"Name": "Foo", "Id" : 1234, "Rank": 7});
```

- Demo of the above example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8b6Lm/1/)
- You can find more info in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Hope this helps. Happy coding. :)

Comment: Thank you! That is the solution I needed. Thanks for replying so quickly AND going to the effort of putting up the demo on the jsfiddle site. I am very grateful for your help.  After hours of fruitless efforts, it is so good to now have this working.

Comment: I am glad that it helped you. I have edited the answer to correct one semicolon(;) mistake after the `password` variable declaration.